# Combine multiple gt tables to single one plot

Tags: r, cowplot, gt, patchwork, gtextras

With code below (edited basing on code from [here](https://github.com/thomasp85/patchwork/issues/203)) I generates two example tables with `gt` package:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(patchwork)
library(gt)

p1 <- mtcars %>% 
  head(5) %>% 
  gt()

p2 <- mtcars %>% 
  tail(5) %>% 
  gt()

# using wrap elements because this seems to be the answer to non-ggplot grobs e.g. #164 
wrap_elements(full = p1 | p2)
grid.arrange(p1, p2, ncol=2, top="Main Title")
```

Out:

```
Error in p1 | p2 : 
  operations are possible only for numeric, logical or complex types
```

I hope to combine them into one as for ggplot objects: `p <- (p1 | p2)` using `patchwork` package, but I didn't find an effective answer yet.

I also try to convert it to ggplot using [as_ggplot()](https://rdrr.io/cran/ggpubr/man/as_ggplot.html) function:

```
library(bstfun)

mtcars %>%
  head(5) %>%
  gt() %>% 
  as_ggplot()
```

But it raises an error:

```
Error: '.assert_package' is not an exported object from 'namespace:broom.helpers'
```

Is it possible to do so? Thanks for your help at advance.

Reference:

[R - combine two gt objects in a single page output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68523913/r-combine-two-gt-objects-in-a-single-page-output)

Comment: if you are not restricted to `gt`, these might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60349028/how-to-add-a-table-to-a-ggplot

Comment: Thanks, but I need to use `gt` since most of plots were done with it. :(

Comment: Another possible option is to filter two parts of data (`head` and `tail` of `mtcars`), plot two parts separately, but the two parts are arranged horizontally to form one figure, but I am not sure if it's possible to do that with `gt`.

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65835639/arrange-gt-tables-side-by-side-or-in-a-grid-or-table-of-tables

Comment: Thanks for sharing, this seems give me hope to solve problem, I'll try @stefan

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can offer to you this solution:

**1. We take your data:**

```
   p1 <- mtcars %>% 
      head(5) %>% 
      gt()

   p2 <- mtcars %>% 
      tail(5) %>% 
      gt()
```

**2. Let's save your tables into .png's:**

```
    p1 %>%
       gtsave("p11.png", path = "Your_working_dir")
    p2 %>%
       gtsave("p12.png", path = "Your_working_dir")
```

**3. Let's combine your tables:**

```
    library(cowplot)
    p111 <- ggdraw() + draw_image("p11.png", scale = 0.8)
    p112 <- ggdraw() + draw_image("p12.png", scale = 0.8)
    plot_grid(p111, p112)
```

**Our result:**

[image]

Comment: This is an interesting approach, thanks for sharing.

Comment: @ah bon Good luck in the New year ;)

Comment: You can take a similar approach using the `image_composite` function in `magick`.